# How does renaming work?

Tags: operating-system

I don't know if this is stupid or not. But, how does renaming work. Like. Say I rename a `100 GB` file. I can rename it and it doesn't even take a millisecond (ok, maybe it does). But, how can it do it so fast. What's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it like it is an IPv4 packet. It doesn't change all the data but only the header. It is similar as I think. For the NTFS file system, there is a table called MFT (Master File Table) which is vital and describes all the data stored in the file system like file names, timestamps etc. It just updates file name area linked to your file and you don't wait for hours.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer provides some good insights and references to how the file names are stored https://superuser.com/a/511627/173969. The renaming operation is basically a simple alteration of the master file table, this is why it does not depend on the size of the file. Hope if helps!

Answer (score 1):

The actual process depends upon the file system used. Renaming is generally very fast on most systems (unless there are locking problems).

The starting point is the directory that you are concerned with. It will contain the names of the files it contains. The name has to be updated there.

Some file systems also store the file name in the file system's table of files. This file name is used for recovery when directories get corrupted. If something goes wrong, you loose the location of the file in the directory structure but you retain the file itself and the file name. In such file systems, the name has to be updated there as well.

The length of time it takes to rename a file is completely independent of the size of the file.